# basic jquery gallery?

Tags: jquery, image, gallery

I am looking for a basic web gallery such as the one on this site, but preferably with the thumbnails below instead of on the side.

http://shoptheglamourai.com/all/kelly-wearstler-vidalia-dress.html

Does anyone have one they can recommend? Something easy to use would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jquery Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/). It doesnt come with a stylesheet so you can make it looks exactly as you need.

Exmaple: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager3.html

Just make sure you set `timeout:0` so it doesn't auto loop.

EDIT:

They dont use a plugin on their site they just hide one picture and show another picture using this function:

```
function myshowImages(id) {

    $('.bigPic').css({'display':'none'});

    $("#pic-"+id).fadeIn('slow');

}
```

Comment: i've gotten it working, i just cant figure out how to have the images placed horizontally, instead of vertically. any suggestions?